# How do I transfer a wpf media element to a new parent element without the media restarting?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a media element that plays MP4 files in my WPF application. I added a minimize button that transfers the media element to a smaller canvas (Minimizing) but the media restarts every time the button is clicked. I need it to continue playing from where it left off. How should I do this? Pausing the media before clicking the minimize button allows it to continue playing where it left off, but does not work consistently.

```
    public void ResumeMethod() 
    {
        Show_MediaScreen.Position = Show_MediaScreen.Position;

        stopWatch.Start();
        dispatcherTimer.Start();

        Show_MediaScreen.Play();


        btnPlayTiny.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnPauseTiny.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        btnPlay.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnPause.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
    public void PauseMethod()
    {
        Show_MediaScreen.Position = Show_MediaScreen.Position;

        if (stopWatch.IsRunning)
        {
            stopWatch.Stop();
        }
        // elapsedtimeitem.Items.Add(currentTime);
        btnPauseTiny.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnPlayTiny.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        btnPlay.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnPause.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Show_MediaScreen.Pause();
    }

private void ShowMediaScreen_MinimizeControl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        Show_MediaScreen.Height = 200;

        Show_MediaScreen.Width = 250;

        VideoScreen.MouseEnter += new System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler(ShowMediaScreen_Hover_ON);
        VideoScreen.MouseLeave += new System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler(ShowMediaScreen_Hover_OFF);

        MyCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MyCanvas_Max.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;


        try
        {
            PauseMethod();

            FullSize.Children.Remove(Show_MediaScreen);

            MyCanvas_Mini2.Children.Add(Show_MediaScreen);

            ResumeMethod();


        }
        catch { }



        btnPlay.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnPause.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `MediaElement.Position` property to get or set the current position of progress through the media's playback time.

Like you said what do you want to do, you can try the codes below.

First, create a `TimeSpan` object to save the current position:

```
TimeSpan currentPosition = new TimeSpan();
```

You need get the positon when the user click the minimize button:

```
currentPosition = YOUR_MEDIA_ELEMENT.Position;
```

Then when you transfer the media element to a smaller canvas:

```
YOUR_MEDIA_ELEMENT.Position = currentPosition;
```

And for more infomation about the `MediaElement.Position` property, you can read the [MSDN document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.position?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

By default, `MediaElement` closes the media and releases the video from memory when it is unloaded (i.e. removed from its parent).

Set the `MediaElement.UnloadedBehavior` property to `MediaStatue.Manual` to remove it from its parent without stopping the video.